# Google Analytics: how do I get metrics for webpages that were not published on my homepage?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

In Google Analytics, I want to find metrics for my published content, that wasn't published on my homepage.

e.g. 
Article x (appears on homepage) gets 1,000 Pageviews.

Article y (does not appear on homepage) gets 300 Pageviews.

Article z (does not appear on homepage) gets 200 Pageviews.

So I would want to find all the content that did not appear on my home page, in this case articles y and z. Thanks

Comment: Please edit your question and show us what you have tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A fast solution will be to run a query:

```
metrics=ga:pageviews
dimensions=ga:pagePath,ga:previousPagePath
filters=ga:previousPagePath!=/
```

A report will show you the list of articles that were not opened on a homepage.
Replace "/" with the path of your homepage.

BUT If an article was listed on your homepage, never was opened from there, though opened from other sources this report will fail to give you a correct answer. Decide if it's acceptable for you.

Comment: Thanks, I understand your code but what are you using to run this query? Is it Query Explorer?

Comment: Yes, you may use these parameters in either Query Explorer or Core API.